# how to download single file from kaggle website?

Tags: kaggle

[the dataset that i want 1 file from](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data). I want to get one file from it - 'application_train.csv'.

I did `pip install kaggle`. The official page gives me one liner to download the **entire dataset**.

`kaggle competitions download -c home-credit-default-risk`

But i want only 1 file.

something `kaggle competitions download -c home-credit-default-risk application_train.csv`, but it s not working

what's the command to download one file from kaggle?

Answer (score 3):

[the official instructions does have the answer](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api)

1. get the kaggle.json from Account tab under your name
2. place under your Windows/username in windows dir.
3. in jupyter notebook - run command `kaggle competitions files home-credit-default-risk` to list files
4. to download 1 file run `kaggle competitions download home-credit-default-risk -f application_train.csv.7z'`